# Problem downloading files from Ubuntu One cloud

Tags: downloads

I've followed the instructions, but I have this back in my terminal:

```
./u1_downloader
bash: ./u1_downloader: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, can you provide the page where you saw the instructions?

Comment: In addition to @roadmr's request, did you perhaps download a 64bit version on your 32bit machine?  Or a Solaris version? *BSD version?  Double check what you downloaded against your machine's specs (32bit/64bit,Ubuntu,etc).  But really, we need _more_ information.  Show us the instructions you followed, show us what you did to download the `u1_downloader`, not only links, but cut/paste them here so your question can help others later.

Comment: @lornix: There is just a file (not 32 or 64 bits) :( I have got the same problem. I followed these Linux steps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/U1/Downloader/Linux/How_to_Use

Comment: It looks the file provided (http://ubuntuone.com/u1-downloader/u1-downloader.tar.gz) is 64bit: 
$ file u1_downloader 
u1_downloader: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped

Comment: Ugh! UPX packed executable as well!  Sheesh, why not RAR it too, just to be more suspicious.  Not like after downloading a 5meg tar.gz you're going to be bothered about a bit more space.  I'm still figuring you're running a 32bit system and trying to execute this 64bit program.  @costales, could you post result of `file u1_downloader` please, and also `uname -a`

Comment: @lornix: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7691767/

Comment: You're on a 32bit system (indicated by `i686` in uname output), trying to run a 64bit program.  Won't work.  You need a 32bit version of the u1_downloader.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the 32 bits version from here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/U1/Downloader/All/Architectures

Or in terminal, just follow these instructions:

1. Download the file with wget

   `wget 'http://ubuntuone.com/u1-downloader/u1-downloader-32b.tar.gz'`
2. Next, run this command to uncompress the program:

   `tar zxf u1-downloader.tar.gz`
3. Go to the program's newly-created directory by running:

   `cd u1-downloader`
4. Start the program by running:

   `./u1_downloader`

You’ll be prompted for your credentials: enter your email and hit enter, then type in your password and hit enter. If needed, you'll be asked for your 2-factor authentication code as well.

Your files will start downloading and will be saved in the u1-files directory (you can access this folder with the file manager)